# Is there anyone who wants to attend to a physics of philosophy online forum?

Tags: discussion

Is there anyone who wants to attend to a physics of philosophy online forum?

Hello, I'm a high school student in Korea who truly loves physics. Recently, I have been very interested in the philosophy of physics, so I have studied specialized books and major books, and I thought I would like to share them with others.

The philosophy of physics is quite abstract, so many other people probably felt the same way. Places like Reddit and Quora cover too broad a topic, so I thought it would be nice to have a community that is limited to the specific field of philosophy of physics. I think it would be great if we could provide an opportunity for education in this field that people are relatively unfamiliar with, and that we also publish a periodical publication and create a forum for discussion.

I'd probably like to expand the community based on the website. Anyone who wants to study the real philosophy of physics, *leave a comment below*! I would be grateful if you leave an email address as well. (It's okay if you don't know much about this field! It's enough if you can study with fun and enthusiasm.)

Comment: “Physics of philosophy” (in title) $\ne$ “philosophy of physics” (in body).

Comment: ("Attend" may not be the right word. Presumably, it is related to *"publish a periodical publication and create a forum"*)

Comment: Physics Meta Stack Exchange is a site for asking questions about how Physics Stack Exchange operates, not for recruiting PSE members for other purposes (even if those are partially related to physics). This question is off-topic for either PSE or PMSE.

Comment: In general it's a bad idea to ask people for email addresses.  Using SE (or a chat room here) does not require using email addresses.  It's done for user security.

Comment: I’ve hidden a request to share email addresses in this question. Some users put personal contact information in their user profiles.